# I am trying to clear the currently drawn image on the cgcontext

Tags: image, iphone-sdk-3.0, cgcontext

I have drawn a uiimage on a cgcontext

CGContextDrawImage(tempContext, CGRectMake(0,0,myRect.size.width,myRect.size.height), imgRef);

but once user is done with the current image, i want to clear the tempContext so that I can rescale / manipulate the image and redraw it on the same context.

for this i want to clear the the context and make it clean.
I tried CgContextClearRect but it didn't worked :(

Answer (score 7):

try this one, it works for me: CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);